# PHP make echo json_encode() not display information on page

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I have a problem with a `HTML prize hunt game` I'm trying to make. The problem I have is that when I want to grab a value from my database I have to use an `AJAX call on a html page`. But for that to work I need to do echo `json_encode()` which then leads to someone being able to just go to that sidepage `(www.website.com/jsonencode.php)` and just find the `location` of the prize. 
Any help is appreciated :)

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "fkwills";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "FKDatabase";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$query = ("SELECT `markerLocation`, `markerCode`, `used`, `active` FROM `markerInfo`");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result); 

echo json_encode(array("markerLocation"=>$result1[0],"markerCode"=>$result1[1],"used"=>$result1[2], "active"=>$result1[3]));

?>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
var markerCode;
var used;
var active;
var markerLocation;


 function downloadCode() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getMarkerPage.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            markerCode = data.markerCode;
            used = data.used;
            active = data.active;
            markerLocation = JSON.parse(data.markerLocation);
        },
        error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

and yes I call the function `downloadCode();`

Comment: I don't really understand how this game works but the results should only be the one you want to send your user. If it's a guessing game, the client should ask your server if 4 is the right number and ter server respond 'yes or no. You should not send all the results to the client to ask him if he's right. It would be like sending you my password list asking you if your password is in there.

Comment: if you have 'Temporary data to store' like the previously guessed number' or the number of tries, you could store that in a session cookie that is harder to temper with. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php but you will lose that info when the browser close. You could also store stuff in a cookie but this can easily be tempered with (as easy as making ajax request, or spoofing POST form value. I rally think the best approach would be a mix of SQL and session cookie and handle every 'sensitive' thing on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
```

then echo @ PHP only if the method is POST

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    echo json_encode(//............
```

Comment: hi thanks this worked but if someone knows how to get around google chrome they can still go into the network tab on the developer tools and check through that. @Hossam

Comment: @PaulCrovella why is that? it works fine for me its just the network tab that is still the issue